# InfluxDB how to escape square brackets "["

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am querying influx D.B. as shown below,

```sql
select * from measurement where '/cda/stats/@name' =~ /cda\/stats.*/ limit 5;
```

Above query is working fine, but when i try to specify square brackets in the query string it is not working,  for e.g. `"/cda/stats/[name='set']`

```sql
select * from mgmgrand where '/cda/stats/@name' =~ /cda\/stats[name='set'].*/ limit 5;
```

Not sure how to escape square brackets in the above query.

Back slash "\" is not working with square brackets.

Comment: Backslashes _should_ work. Depending on what "not working" means, I think the root of the problem might be a missing `/` between "stats" and "[name='set]'". So you'd end up with something like `/cda\/stats\/\[name='set'\]`

Comment: It's not working. Do i need to escape the single quotes ' as well?

Comment: No - the regex seems to work after fixing that slash, at least if I'm correctly understanding what you're testing against. You can test your expression against one of your values [here](https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html).

Comment: I am trying to read this data:select * from mgmgrand where '/cda-stats/server-api-agg/server-api-server/server-api-stats/@name' =~ /cda-stats\/server-api-agg\/server-api-server\/server-api-stats\/\[name='ExprCntrFarmRead'\].*/ limit 5;
But it is not picking up and in DB value is /cda-stats/server-api-agg/server-api-server/server-api-stats[name='ExprCntrFarmRead'\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this in influx DB and found a weird solution (I don't know why it works).
If your identifer is unquoted changing single quotes to double quotes, replacing `'/cda/stats/@name'` with `"/cda/stats/@name"` seems to fix it.

```
select * from mgmgrand where "/cda/stats/@name" =~ /\[/
//matches the value /cda/stats/[name='set']
```

Without changing the quotes it works fine for value without [ , but doesnt work when trying to match a [ character.

```
select * from mgmgrand where '/cda/stats/@name' =~ /cda/
//matches the value /cda/stats/[name='set']
```

```
select * from val1 where '/cda/stats/@name' =~ /\[/
//does not give an output
```

If you use a quoted identifier replacing `'/cda/stats/@name'` with `"'/cda/stats/@name'"` or `"\"/cda/stats/@name\""` fixes it.